# How to Change the <div> text depending on multiple cehckboxes with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

i'm trying to create an Excel-Form to a Web-form and now i'm stuck at this part: http://jsfiddle.net/J9NAS/40/

```
      <table id="model">
        <tr>
            <th class="auto-style2">Basic</th>
            <th class="auto-style2">Maxi</th>
            <th>Short</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th class="auto-style2">Selection</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2">X</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">X</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>asdasd</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">
                <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="HA" class="basic" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2">X</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">X</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>asdasd</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">
                <input id="Checkbox2" type="checkbox" value="PA" class="basic" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2">X</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">X</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>asdasd</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">
                <input id="Checkbox3" type="checkbox" value="IA" class="basic" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2">X</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">X</td>
            <td>D</td>
            <td>asdasd</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">
                <input id="Checkbox4" type="checkbox" value="SPIN" class="basic" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2">X</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">X</td>
            <td>E</td>
            <td>asdasd</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">
                <input id="Checkbox5" type="checkbox" value="VB" class="basic" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">X</td>
            <td>F</td>
            <td>asdasd)</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">
                <input id="Checkbox6" type="checkbox" value="BWCPN" class="maxi" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">X</td>
            <td>G</td>
            <td>asddas</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">
                <input id="Checkbox7" type="checkbox" value="GBH" class="maxi" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">X</td>
            <td>H</td>
            <td>asdasd</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">
                <input id="Checkbox8" type="checkbox" value="GR" class="maxi" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">X</td>
            <td>I</td>
            <td>dsad</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">
                <input id="Checkbox9" type="checkbox" value="IR" class="maxi" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">X</td>
            <td>J</td>
            <td>asdasds.</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">
                <input id="Checkbox10" type="checkbox" value="CC" class="maxi" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">X</td>
            <td>K</td>
            <td>asdasd.</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">
                <input id="Checkbox11" type="checkbox" value="GA" class="maxi" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">X</td>
            <td>L</td>
            <td>Rasdasd.</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">
                <input id="Checkbox12" type="checkbox" value="GPAT" class="maxi" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">X</td>
            <td>M</td>
            <td>asdasd</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">
                <input id="Checkbox13" type="checkbox" value="GPIN" class="maxi" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
     <h1>Callflow:</h1>

    <div id="status"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#status").change(function () {
            if (("#Checkbox1").attr("checked") === true) {
                $("#status").append("#Checkbox1").val();
            };
        });
    });
</script>
```

i want to show the user what kind of Model he chose (Basic or Maxi). The criteria are shown with the 'X's and depending on what features a user chooses, the text field below the form should show "basic" or "maxi".

Can someone help me with that? My JQuery/JS Skills are very basic, yet.

Comment: to explain the JS: at first i'm trying to just show the values of the checkboxes to see if my code works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $basic = $('.basic'), $maxi = $('.maxi'), $status = $('#status');
    $basic.add($maxi).change(function(){
        if($maxi.filter(':checked').length){
            $status.text('Maxi')
        } else if($basic.filter(':checked').length){
            $status.text('Baisc')
        } else {
            $status.text('')
        }
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sNNZf/)

Comment: This works perfect, thank you! =D would you mind explaining me what you did? as i said, my skills are very basic and i'm trying to learn form all sources ;)

Comment: what is happening here is, if at least one checkbox with class `maxi` is checked then `Maxi` is displayed, else if at least one checkbox with class `basic` is checked then `Basic` is displayed else nothing is displayed

Answer (score 1):

You're using a wrong selector. `#status` belongs to div

```
$("#status").change(function () {
```

so you need to have like

```
 $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function () {
```

based on the value you can show/hide the div.